# Getting Error while Integrating Facebook SSO for iOS5 and iOS6 in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

I am working on app which I finished last 2 years and I also use Facebook integration for just sharing text. Now Client want to work on new version of this app and in new version I have to use Facebook Integration SSO for iOS5 and iOS6 both and in xcode 4.6, I did facebook integration in sample app successfully. But when I am trying to do same thing(added frameworks and few facebook delegates) in project its generates few errors after adding frameworks.

**Frameworks Are:**

- Social.framework
- Accounts.framework
- libsqlite3.0.dylib
- FacebookSDK.framework
- AddSupport.framework

**Error are:**

> /Applications/Xcode 4.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Headers/ACAccount.h:23: error: expected a property attribute before 'weak'
>
> /Applications/Xcode 4.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Headers/ACAccount.h:28: error: expected a property attribute before 'strong'
>
> /Volumes/...../Code/code/iphone/Greggs/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBRequest.h:70: error: duplicate interface declaration for class 'FBRequest'
>
> /Volumes/...../Code/code/iphone/Greggs/FacebookSDK.framework/Headers/FBRequest.h:83: error: redefinition of 'struct FBRequest'
>
> /Volumes/...../Code/code/iphone/Greggs/GreggsAppDelegate.m:126: error: expected ':' before '.' token
>
> /Volumes/...../Code/code/iphone/Greggs/GreggsAppDelegate.m:126: confused by earlier errors, bailing out

I read somewhere that its issue of old compiler which I am using for this current project and now I switch on lates xcode 4.6. but I can't find any healthy solution for this. Kindly help me on this. This will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use ARC in your project?

Comment: No, there is no ARC enabled in this project.

Comment: it seems that you linked to the ARC version of the `ACAccount.h` header file from the `Accounts.framework`, and cause the complication problem